# Is it possible to declare a string with an uninitialized size in assembly?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, irvine32

I am currently declaring my string variable like this:

```
source       BYTE  20 DUP (0)
```

Then, later I have this code:

```
mov edx, OFFSET source                   
mov ecx, SIZEOF source
call ReadString
```

However, when I try to get the length of the string it always returns 20. Is there a way to get the length of what the user types? Or is it possible to declare an uninitialized size for the string? I have searched my textbook and found nothing so far.

Comment: Hey thanks haven't thought of that.

Comment: Sounds like you are still confused about the difference between assembly time and run time.

Comment: If the library provides a `ReadString` function, it very likely provides a `StringLength` function. If you know C, this is much like `scanf` and `strlen`. You have reserved a string with maximum length 20 bytes, but the user can type in a *shorter* string. The `StringLength` function (or whatever it's called) provided by your library should do exactly what Michael Petch suggested, saving you from having to write the code yourself.

Comment: @CodyGray: According to the tag <irvine32>: [StrLength](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fstrlength.htm)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not implemented in the way you're thinking of. If you want to have a "dynamic" string you have to program it by yourself. The "string variable" you declared is actually a buffer that gets the bytes from [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm). Imagine it as a glass of water. The size of the glass doesn't change, i.e. you can't get the volume of the water by asking for the size of the glass.

However, Irvine's [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) returns in `EAX` the amount of characters inputted by the user. Don't forget to add the terminating null when you work with that amount!

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
    buffer BYTE 20 DUP (?)
    msg1 BYTE "SIZEOF = ",0
    msg2 BYTE "Result of ReadString = ",0

.CODE

    main PROC

    lea edx, msg1
    call WriteString
    mov eax, SIZEOF buffer
    call WriteInt
    call CrLf

    mov edx, OFFSET buffer
    mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer - 1        ; "-1": save space for the terminating null
    call ReadString

    lea edx, msg2
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt
    call CrLf

    exit
    main ENDP

END main
```